# Where/How is Ember Data App.Model.find() called?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My Ember app has just one model, Org,

```
App.Org = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

which is called inside the Route model through

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('organization', {path: '/'});
});

App.OrganizationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Org.find();
  }
});
```

and I am using the Local Storage Adapter.

So I expect the `find()` of the LSAdapter to be called.  However it seems like this is not the case as I have put in

```
console.log("inside find of LSAdapter");
```

inside my modified version of LSAdapter's [find function](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L45-L51) but that line is not printed in the console.

Here is the [jsbin's code](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/277/edit), where the js contains the modified LSAdapter on top and my Ember app on the bottom.
Here is the [jsbin running](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/277), please open up the console.

So please help me figure out where/how `find` is called. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting thing is that the `find` method is delegated via `DS.Store`, so if you don't pass an `id` or a query object, it redirects to `findAll` on your adapter. That is why your `console.log` was not printing anything.

You can have a look at the delegation here: [emberjs/data@store.js#428](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/78068419da2209ea050206548d0f5bb69670236b/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L428).

**Bonus**: If you have a route, and it has no children, it should not be a `resource`, unless you are using the implied `index` sub-route.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.route('organization', {path: '/'});
});
```